# How to use built-in `slice` to access 2-d blocks in 2-d array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, slice

I have a 2-d numpy array, for which I would like to modify 2-d blocks (like a 3x3 sub-block on a 9x9 sudoku board). Instead of using fancy indexing, I would like to use the built-in `slice`. Is there a way to make this work? I am thinking that the stride argument (third arg of `slice`) can be used to do this somehow, but I can't quite figure it out. My attempt is below.

```
import numpy as np

# make sample array (dim-1)
x = np.linspace(1, 81, 81).astype(int)
i = slice(0, 3)

print(x[i])
# [1 2 3]

# make sample array (dim-2)
X = x.reshape((9, 9))
```

Say I wanted to access the first 3 rows and first 3 columns of `X`. I can do it with fancy indexing as:

```
print(X[:3, :3])
# [[ 1  2  3]
#  [10 11 12]
#  [19 20 21]]
```

Trying to use similar logic to the dim-1 case with `slice`:

```
j = np.array([slice(0,3), slice(0,3)]) # wrong way to acccess 
print(X[j])
```

Throws the following error:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subscript with `X[:3, :3]`, then behind the curtains you pass a *tuple*, so `(slice(3), slice(3))`.

So you can construct a `j` with:

```
j = (slice(3), slice(3))
```

or you can obtain the `a, b` block with:

```
j = (slice(3*a, 3*a+3), slice(3*b, 3*b+3))
```

so here `a=0` and `b=1` for example will yield the `X[0:3, 3:6]` part. So a block that contains the first three rows and second three columns.

or you can make a tuple with a variable number of items. For example for an `n`-dimensional array, you can make an `n`-tuple that each has a `slice(3)` object:

```
j = (slice(3),) * n
```